Driving 1024x600 TFT LCD using SSD1963
I trying to drive a 10-inch (1024 RGBx600) TFT LCD using SSD1963 Controller. According to the datasheet, SSD1963 has 1215 kB embedded SRAM, which can be used for driving 864 x 480 LCD with 24-bit data format. Accordingly, when I set data format to 16-bit (RGB 565), I expected the required ram equal to (1024x16-bit) x 600 = 1200 Kbytes.
It' seems SSD1963 has enough ram for driving 1024x600 LCD. However, when I do that, the maximum width and heigh that I can control is 864x407 (as shown in the figure).

I used the same code and board for driving 5-inch (800x480) and 7-inch (800x480) LCD, successfully. However, I don't know where the problem is? Do I incorrectly initialize the SSD1963, or the problem is a limitation of the controller!?
The related part of my code (c language code in keil IDE on the STM32L4 MCU) that I use for initializing the SSD1963 for different LCD sizes is as follow:
// Configure the LCD panel: 10.0 inch TFT, 1024(RGB)×600
//a. Set the panel size to 1024 x 600 and polarity of LSHIFT, LLINE and LFRAME to active low 
LCD_Send_Cmd(0xB0);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x0C);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x20);     /* 0x00 0x80 0x20(5') */    // TFT type 
LCD_Send_Dat(0x03);     // Horizontal Width:  1024 -1 = 0x03FF
LCD_Send_Dat(0xFF);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x02);     // Vertical Width :  600 - 1 = 0x0257 
LCD_Send_Dat(0x57);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x2D);    
//b. Set the horizontal period 
LCD_Send_Cmd(0xB4); // Horizontal Display Period  
LCD_Send_Dat(0x04);    // HT: horizontal total period, (display=1024 + non-display=250) – 1 = 1274-1 =  1273 =0x04F9
LCD_Send_Dat(0xF9);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x00);    // HPS: Horizontal Sync Pulse Start Position = Horizontal Pulse Width + Horizontal Back Porch = 16 = 0x10 
LCD_Send_Dat(0x2E);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x30);     // HPW: Horizontal Sync Pulse Width - 1=8-1=7 
LCD_Send_Dat(0x00);    // LPS: Horizontal Display Period Start Position = 0x0000 
LCD_Send_Dat(0x0F);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x00);    // LPSPP: Horizontal Sync Pulse Subpixel Start Position(for serial TFT interface).  Dummy value for TFT interface. 
//c. Set the vertical period 
LCD_Send_Cmd(0xB6);    // Vertical Display Period  
LCD_Send_Dat(0x02);     // VT: Vertical Total (display=600 + non-display=150) Period – 1  =649=0x0289
LCD_Send_Dat(0x89);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x00);     // VPS: Vertical Sync Pulse Start Position  =     Vertical Pulse Width + Vertical Back Porch = 2+2=4  
LCD_Send_Dat(0x10);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x10);     //VPW: Vertical Sync Pulse Width – 1 =1 
LCD_Send_Dat(0x08);     //FPS: Vertical Display Period Start Position = 0 
LCD_Send_Dat(0x00);

// set tear on
LCD_Send_Cmd(LCD_set_tear_on);
LCD_Send_Dat(0x80);

//Setup the MCU interface for 16-bit data write (565 RGB)
LCD_Send_Cmd(0xF0);     // mcu interface config 
LCD_Send_Dat(0x03);     // 16 bit interface (565)


There's nothing in the documentation for the chip or boards based on the chip that indicates that it supports more than 864 pixels per line. Why do you think otherwise? It probably isn't just a question of sufficient memory.

The data sheet of SSD1963 said it support 864 x 480 x 24 bit graphics content. However, I drive LCD with more than 480 lines, which led me to think if the memory being sufficient, I can drive lcd with any sizes.

It seems that the controller uses 24-bit data even we use 16-bit 565 RGB data format. Therefore, the problem is insufficient memory.

How/where are u setting "set_pixel_data_interface", Command 0xF0?

Exactly after the previous code I've sent, I set data format (0xF0 cpmmand). I edit the original question to show that.

There's a fixed-size (1215K) frame buffer, and the chip can increment horizontal and vertical addresses depending on the screen size. This made you think that you can render in any resolution as long as the frame buffer is not filled up. But the chip appears to have a hard limit. To be sure, you can try 800x600 (or 600x800) in 16-bit format (or maybe even lower), and see if the horizontal or vertical is limited.

I found that the problem is the size of frame buffer. Even if I use 16-bit (565 RGB) or 24-bit data, I only can control 1215 x 1024 x 8 pixels. I expected when I used 16-bit (565 RGB), I can control more pixels, which is not possible.
